# Getting AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed during the trimming of a video by using AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios

I am working on an application which deals with the video . Now i want to trim this video by using `AVAssetsExpertSession` But i am getting `AVAssetExpertSessionStatusFailed` during the trimming of this video.Please help me guys.

```
- (void)trimVideo:(NSString *)outputURL assetObject:(AVAsset *)asset
    {

        float videoStartTime=2.0f;
        float videoEndTime=5.0f;
    @try
    {

        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];

        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];

        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

        CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake((int)(floor(videoStartTime * 100)), 100);
        CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake((int)(ceil(videoEndTime * 100)), 100);
        CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, startTime);

        exportSession.timeRange = range;

        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

        [self checkExportSessionStatus:exportSession];

        //[exportSession release];
        exportSession = nil;

    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception Name:%@ Reason:%@",[e name],[e reason]);
    }
}


- (void)checkExportSessionStatus:(AVAssetExportSession *)exportSession
{

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
     {

         switch ([exportSession status])
         {

             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:

                 NSLog(@"Export Completed");
                 break;

             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:

                 NSLog(@"Error in exporting");
                 break;

             default:
                 break;

         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: what error you got in fails state do you have any log?

Comment: I am getting the error in exporting .Please tell me what is the error for which i am unable to trim the video.

Comment: there are many possible reason for example bad url, some method is missing and etc you need to found another way to trim a video and check your code with working code compare it i think there is very small mistake.

Comment: Can you provide me such code because i tried to trim a video by using another code but i am getting the same error.

Comment: let me know if it is working or not?

Comment: atleast you reply of answer is taht working or not...

Comment: Sorry i am too late to reply but this is also not working. @NitinGohel

Comment: that have to work you can check the following code  https://github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider